# pandas iterate rows and then break until condition

Tags: excel, loops, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension

I have a column that's unorganized like this;

```
Name
Jack
James
Riddick

Random value
Another random value
```

What I'm trying to do is get only the names from this column, but struggling to find a way to differentiate real names to random values. Fortunately the names are all together, and the random values are all together as well. The only thing I can do is iterate the rows until it gets to 'Random value' and then break off.

I've tried using lambda's for this but with no success as I don't think there's a way to break. And I'm not sure how comprehension  could work in this case.

Here's the example I've been trying to play with;

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].map(lambda x: True if x != 'Random value' else break)
```

But the above doesn't work. Any suggestions on what could work based on what I'm trying to achieve? Thanks.

Comment: To clarify, the names are spaced, first name and last name. The `'Random Value'` is basically `'status'` and then some numbers underneath it.  I wanted to try and make the script future proof by finding a way to extract names only. I thought if I can iterate the rows in order, I could break as soon as I hit `status`. Only other option is to create a list and manually add names and then use the `isin(names)` function.

Comment: The names will always be clunked together in a row, and the random values clunked together, they won't ever mix. If having some sort of break function isn't possible, then I you're right in the sense that I'd have to create some sort of names list or dict and compare against it instead. But only downside would be everytime a new name is added to the excel sheet, I'd have to update the dict script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find index of row containing 'Random value':

```
index_split = df[df.Name == 'Random value'].index.values[0]
```

Save your random values column for use later if you want:

```
random_values = df.iloc[index_split+1:,].values[0]
```

Remove random values from the Names column:

```
df = df[0:index_split]
```